# Google PlayStore Search for my App is not working

Tags: android, search, google-play

I have uploaded my app a few days ago and it has also got the status published. 
Unfortunately, the app cannot be found via the Google Playstore search.

The name of the app is "Guess the Movie Star".

But if I search for "Guess_the_Movie_Star" I can find my app. 
Does anyone know an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that matter for search. I have published more then 30 apps on play store. Factor that matter for search on play store that is as follow:-

1. Package Name **if your app name is The Rocket News then package name should be like this com.news.therocketnews** (package name consist if three word so first two word should be highly valuable keyword like this because like this is news app so news is highly keyword for this app and com is very common and highly valuable keyword)
2. App Name should be combo of some common keyword and highly searched keyword For Example : **The Rocket News - News | Breaking News | Latest News | Video News**
3. Minimum 20 Downloads must with **5 Rating and Review** it will help a lot in searching algo of play store.
4. App Description Should be very **Clean and with consist of keyword** related to the app
5. For first 2-3 days search your app with package name like this com.news.therocketnews on play store search bar

Answer (score 0):

Try search like this `pub:<your google play a/c name>` in play store search

> Example

`pub:Tencent Games`

Comment: You mean like this: "pub: Guess the Movie Star"

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently uploaded the app, then it'll take some time to be displayed in the search results. Till then you can search it using the package name or app link i.e.:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package
```

Comment: I can find my app when I am searching for "guess_the_movie_star". But not when I search "guess the movie star"

Comment: it'll appear after some time.

Answer (score 0):

though it's a matter off keywords try change your title and description,you can use your application link to find it for the moment